# How to implement DTLS in contiki os and integrate it with coap protocol

Tags: contiki, coap, dtls

https://code.google.com/archive/p/contiki-dtls/ "checked this link but facing problems in integrating as there is no readme here"

https://github.com/renzoe/dtls-contiki/wiki

how to use tinyDTLS in contiki os, can someone explain steps for the same.